# updating local master with remote master

Tags: git, github

I have a branch that I want to merge to the remote, most up-to-date `master`. I have a local, outdated master on my computer. 
I ran `git pull upstream master`, and it retrieved the remote `master`, and that was great, exactly what I wanted. Then, without thinking, i accidentally discarded the changes while switching to another branch.

While on my local master, I have run `git pull`, and `git pull upstream master` many times now, and it always says "Already up to date." when it clearly isn't. At first `git pull upstream master` worked just fine, but now it doesn't, and the machine thinks it is up to date when it isn't. How can I make my local master the same as the remote one again?

Comment: How did you accidentally modified the master? AFAIK `git pull` does two things: 1. `fetch` the remote and 2. `merge` it to your local branch. Checking out another branch and then going back to `master` should not change anything on master. Can you reproduce the steps in a mock repo and post the commands?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Well, typically when I have an outdated master locally and want to merge recent changes in a branch (say, my_branch) to master (both locally and remotely), I do the following,

- Checkout the `master` branch locally.
- Run `git pull --rebase origin master` (This pulls down the most up-to-date changes on master locally)
- Checkout local branch say `my_branch`
- Run `git pull --rebase origin master`(This updates your local branch against the most recent master on remote. You may need to resolve the conflicts here (if any that is))
- checkout the `master` branch locally, again.
- Run `git merge my_branch`
- Run `git push origin master`

Comment: git pull --rebase origin master did it. thanks a lot

Comment: You will still need to run `git reset --hard upstream/master` as written in @Gianni Carlo's answer below.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36540803/5683686

Answer (score 22):

If you have already done a `git fetch upstream` You can try doing while in your branch master:

```
 git reset --hard upstream/master
```

This will set your current branch to be exactly like your upstream master (it will discard any local changes btw). Check your last commit to confirm that you've got the latest in your local

Comment: This command needs to be executed with extreme care as it will lead to losing your local file changes (if any). Step-wise rebasing as mentioned in another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36542146/5644090) is much advisable :)

Comment: I would argue that no, since the OP in this specific case, wants to have his local master to be *exactly the same as the remote master*. Since OP doesn't care about local changes, rebasing might be tedious in this case. But I agree that if you don't want to lose your local changes, you shouldn't use this command

Comment: You may want `git reset --hard origin/master` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me like charm

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull`
3. `git checkout <your local branch>`
4. `git pull --rebase --autostash origin master`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps ->

```
git checkout master
git stash
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull -r
```